# Can a subset of the indexing set of a RV, given rise to a non-stationary time series, be considered weakly stationary or vice versa?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, stationarity

Given a non-stationary time series $X_t$, is it possible that a subset $[t_1, t_2]$ of the indexing set is considered weakly stationary? And also, given a weakly stationary time-series, can a subset of its indexing set be considered non-stationary?

Thanks :)

EDIT: As pointed out by @Chris Haug, @Richard Hardy I was originally thinking about subsets of the support of the RV that generated the series, rather than about subsets of the indexing set. However, as the answer by @Dilip Sarwate made clear, that type of definition would not be directly related to weakly stationary processes anymore, but would need to refer to a different sort of classification.

Since I haven't seen any duplicate questions, I leave the question up as an answer to the indexing-set question though. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "a subset of a time series"? I thought you meant a subset of the indexing set, in which case the answer to the first question is yes and the second is no. But you seem to be subsetting the support of a random variable instead.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I was thinking about subsets of the support of the RV that generated the series. So the RV would have to be defined piecewise. Yes right, now coming back to it the first question this would carry over from thinking about the indexing set. Still not sure about the second one though...

Comment: Just to prevent confusion, could you try to rephrase the title (and the body) to make it absolutely clear you are subsetting the support of the random variable rather than the indexing set? Because a conventional reading of the title suggests the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris Haug says, the answer to the second question "Can a subset of a weakly stationary time series be nonstationary?" is No.

A time series is modeled as a discrete-time random processes, that is as a collection of indexed random variables $\{X(n)\colon n \in \mathbb T\}$ where the index set $\mathbb T$ is a subset of $\mathbb Z$, the set of all integers. A typical $\mathbb T$ is the set $\{0,1, 2, \ldots, N-1\}$.  The time series is called *weakly stationary* if it satisfies two criteria (Note: *both* criteria must be satisfied):

1. The mean of the time series is a constant, that is, $E[X(k)]$ has the *same* value $\mu$ for *all* $k \in \mathbb T$.
2. Given any fixed integer $m \in \mathbb Z$, $E[X(k)X(k+m)]$ has the same value $R_X(m)$ *for all* $k$ such that $k, k+m \in \mathbb T$. Note that the value of $E[X(k)X(k+m)]$ is dependent on $m$ but *is not* a function of $k$ at all.

The function $R_X(m)$ is called the *autocorrelation function* of the time series, and has the properties that $|R_X(m)| \leq R_X(0)$. That is, the autocorrelation function has a peak at the origin.

So, how can a weakly stationary time series be *nonstationary,* say between $k_1$ and $k_2$? If the mean varies from the fixed value $\mu$ that it enjoys for $k<k_1$ and $k>k_2$, Criterion 1 is not satisfied, and so the assumption of weak stationarity falls to the ground. If for some $k \in \{k_1,k_1+1,k_1+2 \ldots, k_2\}$, it so happens that $E[X(k)X(k+m)]$ has value that depends on both $k$ and $m$, or is not equal to $R_X(m)$, Criterion 2 is not satisfied, and the claim of weak stationarity is no longer valid.

If a time series is to be called weakly stationary, it must satisfy the two criteria *for* **all** *time instants* such that $k \in \mathbb T$ and $k+m \in \mathbb T$. Of course, the OP can always coin a new name (say *Schroederian weak stationarity* or weakly stationary in the Schroederian sense) for a time series that is weakly stationary most of the time but fails to be weakly stationary for certain time instants or for certain time intervals, and if the notion is useful and leads to new insights, others will adopt it too.

Turning to the first question, we see that it is just the mirror image of the second question. A time series that is weakly stationary in the Schroederian sense can always be regarded as a nonstationary time series that happens to satisfy the criteria for weak stationarity every now and then.

Comment: What do you mean by *If the mean varies from the fixed value $\mu$ that is enjoys for $t<t_1$ and $t>t_2$*?

Comment: In mathematical statistics, a time series is a _random process:_  a collection of indexed random variables, say $\{X(t)\colon t\in \mathbb Z\}$, and if the time series is _assumed_ to be weakly stationary, then all the $X(t)$'s must have the same mean (or expected value) $\mu\in \mathcal R$. If some of the random variables, say those for $t \in [t_1, t_2]$, have means that are _different_ from $\mu$, then the time series can no longer be called weakly stationary. So, I am questioning the OP's notion of a weakly stationary time series that fails the criteria for $t \in [t_1, t_2]$...(continued)

Comment: ...(continued) but is still said to be weakly stationary _at some time instants_ but nonstationary in others.  How does such a process differ from a generally nonstationary one? Are we now imposing the condition that in a nonstationary time series, _all_ the mean values must be distinct, else the time series might be weakly stationary for those instants when the mean repeats but not for others? And what if $X(1)$ and $X(2)$ have the same mean $\mu$ while  $X(3)$ and $X(4)$ have the same mean $\lambda\neq \mu$?

Comment: I think I get your idea, but I do not get the grammar of the sentence. Are there some words that are missing from it perhaps?

Comment: I have posted an answer that probably contradicts yours (I am not fully sure). What do you think about it?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! The grammar is now fine, and the answer is clear (even though you have kept the $X(t)$ notation that I think is more commonly used in continuous time vs. $X_t$ for discrete time). Thanks also for the comment under my answer. I got your point, will think about it a bit more and delete my answer if I deem it wrong on the basis of what you wrote. (There seem to be some subtleties about indexing which work differently in proofs of stationarity than e.g. in proofs of convergence of sequences.)